# HAXM device is not found in Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, haxm

I am trying to develop a mobile application using Android Studio but I am always getting a pop message with below message.

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM device is not found.

[image]

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that HAXM is installed properly. Try disabling 3rd party security software if the problem still occurs.

Things I have tried:

1. Installed the HAXM installer on SDK Manager
2. Went to Extras -> Intel -> Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe". But getting error message as "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver."

[image]

I am using:
Android Studio 3.5 on Windows 7.

1. Could you kindly let me know that Windows 7 supports Android application development using Android Studio?
2. Could you kindly let me how this issue can be addressed?

Comment: As the dialog states you have to enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings. I would suggest looking up a tutorial on how to access the BIOS for your particular PC model. Then you would also need to look up where in the BIOS the Intel Virtualization Technology option is located. I wish I could be more specific but every PC BIOS is different depending on the model.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: This error appears in spite of VT-x activated.

Answer (score 18):

For me, the problem was exactly in the HAXM version (Currently 7.5.4). I rolled back to version 7.5.1 and it worked.

Did the following (For Windows):

1. Found the HAXM installer (Tools -> SDK Manager, Follow the Android SDK Location\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe), using it deleted HAXM.
2. I downloaded HAXM from an older version (7.5.1) from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
3. Installed
4. Restarted Android Studio and it worked

Comment: This worked.. after wasting almost a day searching for a solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It works like a charm in Windows 7. Check the status by enterning the command, sc query intelhaxm

Answer (score 12):

To solve this problem, download and install this update https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148 from Microsoft and then restart your computer.

This solved it for me on windows7 64 bits and android studio 3.5.3

I hope it will help you as well.

Comment: This solved it for me. Big thanks! Running on HAXM 7.5.6 now.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was solved by disabling Hyper-V on Windows 10.
The below are the steps to disable Hyper-V:

- In "Control Panel", select "Programs and Features".
- Select "Turn Windows features on or off".
- Expand "Hyper-V", expand "Hyper-V Platform", and then clear the "Hyper-V Hypervisor" check box.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I uninstall 7.6.5 from SDK manager and download 7.6.6 from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases, install it as Administrator, then reboot. It works.