# error in creating an android virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed Android Studio, and everything looks fine.
When I try to install a virtual device, I could notice the following error message although I have installed HAXM in the android studio & I have also downloaded some SDK platforms.

[image]

How can I run the emulator?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191392/haxm-device-is-not-found-in-windows-7

Comment: what do you mean install verticall device? you can rotate the device after you install it

Comment: I want to install emulator device